# Reg Expression to match date format

Tags: javascript, regex

i need to verify that my text box should contain only- `numbers,-,/,.`

i have written fallowing function but it's not working..

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="isValidDate(this);"/>



    function isValidDate(f){ 
      var regDate = '/^[0-9]*|\/*\|-*|.*$/';
        alert("called::"+f.value);   
      if(!regDate.test(f.value))  
      alert("inside");
        f.value = f.value.replace(regDate,"");  
 }
```

i am getting an error that-`regDate.test is not a function`
am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Title says you're trying to match date format but your question text says that:

```
i need to verify that my text box should contain only- numbers,-,/,.
```

You can try this regular expression:

```
/^[\d\/\.-]+$/
```

Answer (score 1):

No need of quotes.

```
 var regDate = /^[0-9]*|\/*\|-*|.*$/;
 if(!regDate.test(f.value)) ....
```

this will do the check you need

```
/^[\d-/.]*$/.test(string);
```

And to test for a date format you can try something like

```
/\d+[-/.]\d+[-/.]\d+/.test(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `regDate` is a string, not a RegExp object. Create it like so:

```
var regDate = new RegExp("/^[0-9]*|\/*\|-*|.*$/");
```

or

```
var regDate = /^[0-9]*|\/*\|-*|.*$/;
```

Comment: Also, the regex itself is so wrong to be beyond salvation - just removing the slashes still leaves a horrible mess.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: I make no comment on the quality of the regex, only that he didn't have a RegEx object.